# extjs tree panel. How to bring front

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

How can I bring tree panel to front in extjs?
When I click and opening the tree panel he is under the another component. How can I fix this problem?

```
...showMetricPicker : function(metricField) {
        if (this.metricPicker == null) {
            this.metricPicker = Ext.create('MetricPicker', {
                renderTo: this.getEl(),
                style: {
                    zIndex: 99999
                },
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                border: true,
                selModel: {
                    mode: 'SINGLE',
                    listeners: {
                        beforeselect: function(tree, node) {
                            //allow only metric selection not group
                            return node.get('leaf');
                        }
                    }
                },
                listeners: {
                    scope: this,
                    itemdblclick : function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                        this.metricDblClick(record);
                    }
                }
            });
            this.metricPicker.btnShowCollectingMetrics.setVisible(false);

            this.metricPicker.btnShowCommonMetrics.setVisible(false);
            this.stopEventOnMouseDown(this.metricPicker);
        } else {
            this.metricPicker.show();
        }
        this.metricPicker.metricField = metricField;
        this.metricPicker.getEl().alignTo(metricField.getEl(), 'tl-tl');.....
```

Comment: You'll have to provide us more information. Drop the view code in, and we can take a look...

Comment: possible duplicate of [show tree panel front of all divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631475/show-tree-panel-front-of-all-divs)